# Geographic locators within Polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, administrative-boundaries

I have a list of geographic locators and a boundary file. In QGIS, is there any way merging them together to create a lookup saying this boundary contains these locators? Not the number the actual locator i.e. postcode, easting/northing.

Comment: Just to be clear: your locators would be some sort of points of interest, and the boundaries would be some area like a single municipality, or city district?

Comment: Please provide a example subset of your data. This will simplify further answers. I believe you should somehow geocode (get locations) your locators. Then you could test if a given location (point) is in your boundary.

Comment: The boundary is school catchment area and locators are each child's home address. I want to know which locators lie within each catchment area. I have 10,000 postcodes so testing each one individual is not something I am prepared to do!

Comment: It sounds like a term you should search for is `spatial join`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Spatial Tools 'Analysts Tools' in QGIS

This Guide **'Tutorial: Spatial Analysis - Points in Polygon '** is a good example how to do **'Points in a Polygon'**

http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-spatial-analysis-points-in.html